# Convert OData Uri to his equivalent Linq expression

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm creating a WCF service whose result is not a strict OData feed (for complicated reasons, business strategy, etc). In addition, the format of the URL is slightly different from OData although most of its features are very similar.

How I can transform the URI in a Linq Expression tree?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at Linq2Rest - https://bitbucket.org/jjrdk/linq2rest. It parses an OData query into a LINQ expression, and the other way around. It's available on Nuget as well.

Comment: The BitBucket repo has been removed. The link is invalid

Answer (score 2):

Currently this functionality is not exposed on its own. And writing it yourself is rather complex (depends on what type of queries you need to support and on your model).
Is it really necessary to deviate from the OData protocol? Maybe what you need to do can be achieved through other means.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's necessary because business strategy changes keywords and returned feed is slightly different (ex: entry payload in custom extension).

Comment: I have to transform the Uri that receives into a Linq query. If it were as OData, no problem because WCF Data Services already does all the work. The problem is that internally it's almost like OData but with a different Uri format.

Comment: I'm currently "decoding" the Uri and through Dynamic Linq, launch queries.

Comment: using Dynamic Linq I could successfully build queries. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You can use following nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Community.OData.Linq

It allows to use OData text query parameters in linq expresson for any IQuerable without ASP.NET dependency

```
var result = query.OData().Filter("Id eq 1 or Name eq 'n3'").OrderBy("Name desc").ToArray();
```